# Pass ID to url to get using bootstrap modal and use that ID to query in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

How can I get the ID from my blade template and pass it to URL using bootstrap modal.
Please see below code.

Controller

How can I pass id to URL to get the "17" so that I can do the query in controller.

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) {

        $platforms = User::with('platforms')->where('id', 17)->get();
        $users = User::all();
        return view('admin.user.index', [
                'users' =>  $users,
                'platforms' =>  $platforms,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Blade - below is my view in blade template including the javascript to do the modal. But whenever I click the button "View" modal will pop up but the data inside the select tag is NULL but when I put ID (example "17") in the controller data will show.

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>View</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td> 
               <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-id="{{$user->id}}" data-bs-target="#viewModal">
               </button>
            </td>
        <tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>




<div class="modal fade" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialo">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input readonly type="text" name="id_name" id="id">
                      
                        <select name="platform" id="platform" class="form-control">

                            @foreach($user_platforms as $user_platform)

                                @foreach($user_platform->platforms as $platform)

                                <option value="{{$platform->id}}">{{$platform->title}}</option>
                                @endforeach

                            @endforeach

                        </select>
                    </div>
                
                        <button type="submit" class="fw-bold btn fw-bold bg-primary text-white">Add new</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<script>
    var viewModal = document.getElementById('viewModal')
    viewModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var button = event.relatedTarget
    var id = button.getAttribute('data-bs-id')

    var modalBodyID = viewModal.querySelector('.modal-body #id')

    modalBodyID.value = id

    });
</script>
```

Comment: where is you routes

Comment: Your form `action` attribute is empty...

Comment: Here's my route

Comment: Route::controller(UserController::class)->group(function(){
    Route::get('admin/users', 'index');
    Route::post('admin/users/store', 'store');
    Route::put('admin/users/update', 'update');
    Route::post('admin/users/store_new_platform', 'store_new_platform');
});

Comment: The problem @GertB. is I need to fetch data to select tag when I click button view in my table action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use route model binding.

```
//in your routes for example
Route::post('/model/{model}', [YourController::class, 'method'])
->name('myRoute');

//in your controller
public function method(Model $model){


//laravel will find the record with given ID in myRoute route
//if the given id in your route is 17, $model will be the record with id: 17

}
```

Comment: But how can I pass the {model} to the URL. I am using bootstrap modal. When ever I click view URL don't change.

Comment: can you show your web.php file

Comment: in the form tag you must set action="{{route('theNameOfYourRoute')}}"   and your url should be something like /model/17

Comment: In table there's a row of user they have action button which is view. Now, how can I get the ID pass to the URL when I click view button. View button show popup modal without changing the URL I just pass the the "id" of the user using data-id which like this...   <button data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-id="{{$user->id}}" data-bs-target="#viewModal">View</button>

Comment: There is no form tag on this button just button with data-id.